# Date picker crashes when used

Tags: android, crash, datepicker

I am using a standard date picker to allow the user to pick a date. After this I will then calculate the days between the current date and the date which was picked.

The problem is when the date picker is fired off the app crashes, even though I had it working before i put in the joda time API. The code I am using for the date picker is:-

```
mDateDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateDisplay);
    mPickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickDate);
    // add a click listener to the button
    mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });
     //get the current date
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    cYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    cMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    cDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    Date past = new Date(cYear, cMonth, cDay); // current Date
    Date today = new Date(mYear, mMonth, mDay); // date Choosen by the user
    int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(past), new DateTime(today)).getDays();
    mDateDisplay.setText(""+days);
 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =
            new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                      int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mYear = year;
                    mMonth = monthOfYear;
                    mDay = dayOfMonth;
                    //updateDisplay();
                }
            };
           @Override
            protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
                switch (id) {
                case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
                    return new DatePickerDialog(this,
                                mDateSetListener,
                                mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                }
                return null;
            }
```

I have an updateDisplay() method which is being references but I have commented everything to do with it out because I don't think I need it for what I am trying to do. For those interested here it is:

```
private void updateDisplay() {
        mDateDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
                    // Month is 0 based so add 1
                    .append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
                    .append(mDay).append("-")
                    .append(mYear).append(" "));
   }
```

People asked for the logcat output here is is

> 03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: current should be >= start and <= end
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.widget.NumberPicker.setCurrent(NumberPicker.java:288)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDaySpinner(DatePicker.java:364)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.widget.DatePicker.updateSpinners(DatePicker.java:350)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.widget.DatePicker.init(DatePicker.java:346)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.(DatePickerDialog.java:124)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.(DatePickerDialog.java:83)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutChoice.onCreateDialog(WorkoutChoice.java:113)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2513)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:888)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2588)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2555)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at com.b00348312.workout.WorkoutChoice$2.onClick(WorkoutChoice.java:49)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>   03-17 17:47:42.343: E/AndroidRuntime(8122):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: when "the app crashes" it is always a good time to take a look what logcat is saying. (or posting it here, so we can see it. that makes it much easier to help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can see the example here that i have put the date and time picker dialog and set it to the textView

http://typicaljava.blogspot.in/2012/02/date-picker-time-picker-dialog-and-set.html

Hope this might helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing simply initialise your values with any date as -

```
                    mYear = 2013;
                    mMonth = 5;
                    mDay = 30;
```

And you will not get force close then.

Thanks